# Get a String out of another using arrays and foreach loops

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, explode

I want to create a string out of another where:

1- The first string is: "4-3|5-2|9-6|7-1|2-8"

2- The new string must be: "4, 5, 9, 7, 2"

I have this piece of code but it doesn't work:

```
$string_1 = '4-3|5-2|9-6|7-1|2-8';

$array_1 = explode('|', $string_1);

$string_2 = '';

foreach ( $array_1 as $item ) {

    $array_2 = explode('-', $item);

    foreach ( $array_2 as $item_id => $item_value ) {

        $string_2 .= ($string_2 == '') ? $item_id : ', ' . $item_id;

    }

}
```

Comment: Which language? (Looks like PHP to me...) And when you say "doesn't work" what does it do?

Comment: @Almo, Yes for sure it's PHP and for the result it's like this:

In the DB: 1-5|2-7|3-1|4-4|5-5|6-3|7-2|8-2|9-6|13-2

The result: 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 3, 7, 2, 8, 2, 9, 6, 1, 2

Comment: You can edit the result you're getting into your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using [RegEx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for this task?

The code using regular expressions:

```
$string_1 = '4-3|5-2|9-6|7-1|2-8';
preg_match_all('/(\d+)-\d+\|?/',$string_1,$matches);
$string_2 = implode(", ", $matches[1]);
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bd9a246525e66cb87714185419031b0dcc0aaa59)

It's much more efficient than looping through each character of a string.

---

**The Regex explained:**

The regex visualized as a RailRoad diagram:
[image: RegEx]

- `(\d+)`: The first `\d` matches a digit. The `+` means one or more times. The `()` around it creates a group which means that the match will be stored within the `$matches` array
- `-`: Followed by a simple dash
- `\d+`: Then there comes another digit one or more times
- `\|?`: And a pipe character `\|` (which needs to be escaped). The `?` means that there is exactly one or no pipe.

[preg-match-all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) will then search for all possible (repeated) matches within the given string.

Comment: While this probably works, it doesn't help the person understand how to solve these kinds of problems because regexes are *opaque*. :) Maybe include an explanation about how your regex works.

Comment: Upvoted, very nice answer now. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using `$item_id` but it represents the `$array_2` index. Try this:

```
foreach ( $array_1 as $item ) {
    $array_2 = explode('-', $item);
    $string_2 .= ($string_2 == '') ? $array_2[0] : ', ' . $array_2[0];
}
```

The second loop is not necessary, it will check 2 times for each row of `$array_1`, so you will retrieve all values instead of the first one.

Answer (score 2):

What you did was almost correct. You just needed to concatenate the strings in the foreach loop after explode.

```
$array_1 = explode('|', $string_1);

$string_2 = '';


foreach ( $array_1 as $item ) {

    $array_2 = explode('-', $item);

    $string_2.= $array_2[0].' ';

}
echo $string_2;
```